# Radioactivity interpreted through Probability

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Could anyone define the Decay Constant through probablity. I have not studied this concept, and it is not mentioned in my textbook. Please Help.

Comment: If you search for radioactivity and probability distribution, you should find some information about the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a probability $p$ that an atom will decay in any given second, you can determine the decay constant as follows:

Call the total activity $A$. Then $\frac{dA}{dt} = -pA$ by my definition of $p$ - because if you have a large number $N$ of atoms, then in a given second $pN$ on average will decay.

Not I can integrate that equation, and get $A_t = A_0 e^{-pt}$

We are used to writing a decay curve in terms of $A=A_0 e^{-t/\tau}$, so it follows that $\tau = 1/p$

You can compute the half life (instead of the "1/e life") with a simple mathematical manipulation. I will leave that as an exercise for you. Hint - for what value of $t$ is $e^{-t/\tau}=\frac12$? That is the half life...